# Make specs pending conditionally

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3

In my app, I sometimes write tests using iterations like this:

```
%w[one two three].each do |number|
  it 'is going to fail under several circumstances' do
    expect(someting_from(number))
  end
end
```

And I know that sometimes for several instances in the array I iterate over this spec can temporarily fail but it's going to be fine some days after, so I want to conditionally skip them, using internal RSpec pending mechanics, so I get notified when this spec stops failing. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: _"I want to conditionally skip them"_ – based on what? And how can you get notified that they stop failing if RSpec is told to skip them?

Comment: BTW, I don't recommend writing code to hide or silence test failures. If you get accustomed to failing tests, you might ignore or overlook an actual problem. Work on the root cause instead. Figure out why your tests fail on some days but pass on others. Then eliminate that aspect from your tests. It's much better to have a reliable test suite.

Answer (score 3):

One can use `pending` [inside an example](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/pending/pending-examples#pending-any-arbitary-reason,-with-no-block) with `if`. Just like this:

```
%w[one two three].each do |number|
  it 'is going to fail under several circumstances' do
    pending("It's not your fault") if we_know_about_this(number)
    expect(someting_from(number))
  end
end
```

Comment: You can also just not define the tests in the first place by wrapping the definitions themselves in an `if`. It depends if you want to "skip" them, or just ignore them altogether.

Comment: As I stated in the question, I want to be notified that these tests are no longer fail, and `skip` is the perfect way to do this. Not defining them won't give me that information. And we all know, that mosts tests that are commented out, marked with `xit` or smth like these most probably are never going to perform again, 'cause no one will go back to them =)

Comment: Oh, I get that sometimes you want them to show up as explicitly skipped. I'm just explaining how you can skip the skips entirely *if that works better for you*.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you don't need them to skip, you can change expectation for a particular item. When the test will be fixed, your test case will fail and you get notified:

```
%w[one two three].each do |number|
  it 'is going to fail under several circumstances' do
    if number == 'two'
      expect(something_from(number)).to be false
    else
      expect(something_from(number))
    end
  end
end
```

When `something_from('two') == false`

```
...

Finished in 0.01532 seconds (files took 0.80331 seconds to load)
3 examples, 0 failures
```

When `something_from('two') == true`

```
.F.

Failures:

  1) is going to fail under several circumstances
     Failure/Error: expect(something_from(number)).to be false
     
       expected false
            got true
     # ./spec/conditional_spec.rb:7:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.0175 seconds (files took 0.79527 seconds to load)
3 examples, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/conditional_spec.rb[1:2] # is going to fail under several circumstances
```

**UPD**

With `pending` to fail tests when a particular test stops failing:

```
%w[one two three].each do |number|
  it 'is going to fail under several circumstances' do
    if number == 'two'
      pending
      expect(something_from(number))
    else
      expect(something_from(number))
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You do not recommend using rspec's skip at all? Or in which situation would you recommend using it otherwise?

Comment: You mentioned a notification when you can fix your test. In my solution, the notification will be quite explicit. Use `skip` or not it is up to you.

Comment: `skip` also shows a notification if the skipped test stops failing and start passing. And you saying you do not recommend skipping. Why?

Comment: I didn't say that I don't recommend `skip`. With `skip` your tests just stay green always, as far as I know only `pending` will fail tests when a test case stops failing.

Comment: I added an example with `pending` to my answer.

Comment: That's the moment I realized I was thinking of `pending`, not of `skip` for all of this time. I wanted to use pending, for sure. Thank you!